# Error :Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) while using django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, django-rest-framework

I use in my study project django rest framework.I get an error 403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect, when I try to save using the POST method. Here is my code html

```
<form id = "product_form" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type = "hidden" name = "id" id = "id">
    <p>Назвние:<input name = "name" id = "name"></p>
    <p><input type = "reset" value = "Oчистить"></p>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Сохранить">
</form>
```

Here is my code js:

```
let productUpdater = new XMLHttpRequest();
productUpdater.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {

        if (productUpdater.readyState == 4) {
            if ((productUpdater.status == 200) || (productUpdater.status == 201)) {
                listLoad();
                name.form.reset();
                id.value = '';
            } else {
                window.alert(productUpdater.statusText)
            }
        }
    }
);


name.form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // let vid = id.value, url, method;
    let vid = id.value;
    if (vid) {
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/api_category/' + vid + '/';
        method = 'PUT';
    } else {
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/api_category/';
        method = 'POST';
    }
    let data = JSON.stringify({id: vid,nameCategory: name.value});
    productUpdater.open(method, url, true);
    productUpdater.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    productUpdater.send(data);
})
```

Here is my views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def api_products(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        productsAll = CategoryMaskarad.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(productsAll, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
def api_rubric_detail(request, pk):
    product = CategoryMaskarad.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT' or request.method == 'PATCH':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        product.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
 path('api_category/<int:pk>/', api_rubric_detail),
 path('api_products/', api_products),
 path('api/drf-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
```

I added the last path and logged in. In the api interface it became possible to add to the api using the post method, but with the help of js in my html I cant add data.Help me, please

Comment: Use csrf_exempt. It'll solve your problem for now. It could be used as a decorator for your view functions...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this solution cannot be used in production because it is not safe. This is true?

Comment: Yes, it's not safe to do so. I think [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) can help you. It says to pass the token manually with each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when passing data in form to a django rest framework, you do not add the csrf_token tag before forms, rather you pass it as a header when sending api post on your endpoint.
Add this line after

try adding this function into your codes to get the values of csrftoken

```js
let getCookie = (name)=>{
        var cookieValue = null;
        if(document.cookie && document.cookie !== ''){
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
          for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if(cookie.substring(0, name.length+1)===(name+'=')){
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length+1));
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return cookieValue;
      }
```

and then change the value you use in x-csrf-token and make it

> productUpdater.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

> productUpdater.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', getCookie("csrftoken"));

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem, I get a 403 error Forbidden

Comment: try checking out the changes in the answer, add the getCookie functionalities, they worked for me in a case like that

Comment: Not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I have this option. He is work.I added to js file:

```
name.form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // let vid = id.value, url, method;
    let vid = id.value, url, method;
    if (vid) {
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/api_category/' + vid + '/';
        method = 'PUT';
    } else {
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/api_category/';
        method = 'POST';
    }
    let data = JSON.stringify({id: vid, nameCategory: name.value});
    productUpdater.open(method, url, true);
    productUpdater.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    productUpdater.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
    productUpdater.send(data);
})
```

and I added to html file:

```
<script>
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
</script>
```